# Невыполняется остальная часть скрипта jquery

Tags: jquery

Здравстуйте! 
У меня проблема. 
У меня есть код `jquery`, но он выполнятеся почему только первая половина. При нажатии на кнопку с `id button` срабатывает первая функция которая прячет элемент content за экран, при этом текущее значение `id` кнопки меняется на `id button1`. которая в дальнейшем "проворачивает" обратные действия, но пробелма заключается в том, что когда первый раз нажимаешь на кнопку с `id button` код выполнятеся и значение `id` меняется на `button1`. При повторном нажатии получается кнопка имеет другой `id` которая соответсвенно выполняет другой код, НО выполняется всегда первая функция и получается постоянно content уходит в лево на `999px`
Вот код.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#button").click(function (){
            $('.content').animate({left: "-=999"}, 120);
            $(this).attr('id','button1');
        });

        $("#button1").click(function (){
            $('.content').animate({left: "+=999"}, 120);
            $(this).attr('id','button');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит использовать как минимум во втором случае функцию не .click(), a [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)/[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Лучше всего вообще использовать [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).